# Count query with fetch relation in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-server-2012

This is my entity :-

```
public class ArticleType extends BaseEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "art_typ_index")
    private Integer             artTypIndex;
    //@Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "art_typ_code", nullable = false)
    private String              artTypCode;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artArtTypIndex", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Article>        articleSet;

    public ArticleType()
    {
    }

    public ArticleType(Integer artTypIndex)
    {
        this.artTypIndex = artTypIndex;
    }

    public ArticleType(Integer artTypIndex, String artTypCode)
    {
        this.artTypIndex = artTypIndex;
        this.artTypCode = artTypCode;
    }

    public Integer getArtTypIndex()
    {
        return artTypIndex;
    }

    public void setArtTypIndex(Integer artTypIndex)
    {
        this.artTypIndex = artTypIndex;
    }

    public String getArtTypCode()
    {
        return artTypCode;
    }

    public void setArtTypCode(String artTypCode)
    {
        this.artTypCode = artTypCode;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Set<Article> getArticleSet()
    {
        return articleSet;
    }

    public void setArticleSet(Set<Article> articleSet)
    {
        this.articleSet = articleSet;
    }   
}
```

I want to check that if for a specific article type is there any Article exists or not.
I have tried this `HQL query` :-

```
SELECT 
count(articleType.artTypIndex)
FROM
ArticleType articleType 
join fetch articleType.articleSet article
where articleType.artTypCode = ?
```

But this query gives me compilation error :-

> org.hibernate.QueryException: 
>   query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list 
>   [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=article,role=com.alstom.autofie2.entity.ArticleType.articleSet,tableName=tbl_article,tableAlias=articleset1_,origin=tbl_article_typ
>   e articletyp0_,columns={articletyp0_.art_typ_index ,className=com.alstom.autofie2.entity.Article}}]

I don't understand what is the problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

the prob is you are selecting the count and not the entity but you are join fetching.

You dont need to load the collection eagerly with an entity you are not fetching.

Try just using join.

or this might work too

```
SELECT 
articleType,count(articleType.artTypIndex)
FROM
ArticleType articleType 
join fetch articleType.articleSet article
where articleType.artTypCode = ?
```